# Views in SQL Server 2012 and later

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I wanted to ask about performance when using a view in SQL 2012 and later.  Let's say I have a complex query that involves multiple joins etc.  Let's say that due to the complexity fo the query and the number of records, this query takes 10 minutes to execute.

I wish to give end users a simple "table" to work with, so I elect to create a view using the query above.  I like the concept of using a view since from my understanding you don't duplicate the data but instead create a "virtual table" which simply references the data where it is stored.  This is obviously efficient compared with creating a second physical table with the relevant data.   But I am worried about performance.

If a user wishes to select a subset of this data using a view, will the entire query need to run to create the view first and THEN the subset of required data will be extracted from this view?  So in other words, for the end user would they be looking at 10+ minutes to get the data they need?

Comment: That entirely depends on the view. With a simple view, the the order by logical processing is unlikely to change, however, this also means that a `WHERE` clause on the view may cause the statement run quicker; due to a significant amount of data being filtered. With a poorly written, or Complex View, the order of Logical processing may well be changed, meaning that parts of the query might have to be parsed first (and those are the slow parts). That doesn't, also, mean that a complex View can't be fast (or a simple slow). The best way to find out would be to test.

Answer (score 4):

The query that references the view is optimized "as a whole" with no real trace that there was ever a view involved at all.

If the optimizer is doing its job well, it won't compute the results of the view first and then filter it - it will push predicates far down, "inside" the view and towards the base tables, if possible.

Another way to think of it, instead of a "virtual table", is instead as a "subquery macro" - that effectively inserts a subquery into the referencing query before optimization occurs, much like a macro might be expanded out in other programming languages before compilation and optimization occur.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what you've done with the view.  If the end user creates a where clause that affects a **column based on an expression**, e.g. casting to different datatypes or case logic to change column values, the entire view will need to be materialized before the filter predicate can be applied.  This can dramatically slow down query processing.

If end user performance is a significant concern and the underlying data does not change frequently, you can put an index on the view.  Anytime the underlying table content changes, SQL Server will execute the view and store the results in an index.  Queries against the view will use the index rather than executing the definition of the view again.  You'll have to pay the storage costs of the view result set, but that can be an effective way to improve performance on **relatively static data**.

However, the first thing I would look into is why the query takes 10 minutes to execute.